# Does R support "Between" operator?

Tags: r, operators, between

I am working on a project which needs R for generating queries.I have come across BETWEEN operator requirement.
Does R support "Between" operator ? like SQL

Comment: There is `data.table::between` which is vectorised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`between`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/between.html) function exists in the ‘dplyr’ package.

You can also write your own:

```
between = function (x, low, high) {
    x >= low & x <= high
}
```